# How do you correctly set up the camera for a ray tracer?

Tags: c++, 3d, raytracing

I'm currently going through the Ray Tracer Challenge book, and I recently got through chapter 7 where we set up a world and camera to render shapes. At the end of the chapter, he gives the reader a an example world to render, so I tried to do it.

[image: How the image should look]

I added all my objects and had one directional light like the book said, but when I tried to render the image, I got something completely wrong.

[image: My scene]

I know the problem is most likely with the camera because I rendered spheres before this chapter without it and they came out fine. I've tried debugging the rays cast, but they seem to follow the pattern that they should based on how I iterate through x and y. The only other possible source of the problem I can think of is the transformation matrices used in the camera (view matrix) and the ones for each sphere. I have a link my [github repo](https://github.com/jperez01/ray-tracer/tree/scene) that contains my code in the scene branch. I was wondering if you guys had any ideas on how I could fix my problem?

Comment: Cool story. Is there a *minimal* example of the code we can help with?

Comment: There is some issue in the field of view. I can say that as the camera looks like it is pointing in the corner and angle is very narrow.